# Uri without authority: hdfs:/data/_spark_metadata error when use spark stream write parquet file on hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I am trying to read data from kafka and save to parquet file on hdfs. 
My code is similar to following, that the difference is I am writing in Java.

```
val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
      .option("subscribe", "topic1")
      .load()

df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)","CAST(value AS STRING)").writeStream.format("parquet").option("path",outputPath).option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/sparkcheckpoint1/").outputMode("append").start().awaiteTermination()
```

However it threw `Uri without authority: hdfs:/data/_spark_metadata` exception, where `hdfs:///data` is the output path.

When I change the code to `spark.read` and `df.write` to write out parquet file once, there is no any exception, so I guess it is not related to my hdfs config.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Uri-without-authority-hdfs-data-spark-metadata-error-when/td-p/182553) there was a suggestion to remove hdfs:// from path, but keep it in checkpoint. However, for me, in HDP Sandbox, it worked both ways with and without hdfs:// in checkpoint:

```
.option("path", "/user/username/outpath")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")
```